# diferentes tipos de passar uma props ou elemento importado

Tags: javascript, html5, react, importação

estou fazendo um código em react que chama um componente passando props, no primeiro caso:

```
import challengAlura from "../../../img/aluraChallenge.png"
import frontMentorCss from "../../../img/frontMentorCss.png"
import maicon from "../../../img/maicon.png"
import rollDice from "../../../img/rollDice.png"
import { Projeto } from "../projeto/Projeto";


export const Projetos = ({isOpen, handleIsOpen, handleIsClose}) => {
   
    const projetos = [
        {imagem: {challengAlura}, descricao: 'chalenge alura', habilidade: 'html css javascript api crud'},
        {imagem: {frontMentorCss}, descricao: 'Front End Mentor', habilidade: 'html css'},
        {imagem: {maicon}, descricao: 'site vendas', habilidade: 'html css javascript'},
        {imagem: {rollDice}, descricao: 'Dado de conselhos', habilidade: 'html css javascript react API'}
    ]

    return projetos.map(projeto => {
        return (<Projeto imagem={projeto.imagem} descricao={projeto.descricao} habilidade={projeto.habilidade}/>)
    })
}
```

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Modal } from "../modal/Modal";

const StyledProjeto = styled.div`
    width: 48%;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    position: relative;

    img {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
    }

    h3 {
        margin-bottom: .5rem;
        text-transform: capitalize;
    }

    p {
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
`

export const Projeto = ({imagem, descricao, habilidade, onMouseOver, onMouseLeave, isOpen}) => {
    return (
        <StyledProjeto onMouseLeave={onMouseLeave} onMouseOver={onMouseOver}>
            <div>
                <Modal isOpen={isOpen}/>
                <img src={imagem} alt={descricao} />
            </div>
            <h3>{descricao}</h3>
            <p>{habilidade}</p>
        </StyledProjeto>
    )
}
```

a imagem é a única coisa que n passa, tirando ela todo o código roda limpo, eu abri todos os caminhos e estavam funcionando. No segundo caso me falaram para fazer assim:

```
import challengAlura from "../../../img/aluraChallenge.png"
import frontMentorCss from "../../../img/frontMentorCss.png"
import maicon from "../../../img/maicon.png"
import rollDice from "../../../img/rollDice.png"
import { Projeto } from "../projeto/Projeto";


export const Projetos = ({isOpen, handleIsOpen, handleIsClose}) => {
   
    const projetos = [
        {imagem: <img src={challengAlura} alt='chalenge alura'/>, habilidade: 'html css javascript api crud'},
        {imagem: <img src={frontMentorCss} alt='Front End Mentor'/>, habilidade: 'html css'},
        {imagem: <img src={maicon} alt='site vendas'/>, habilidade: 'html css javascript'},
        {imagem: <img src={rollDice} alt='Dado de conselhos'/>, habilidade: 'html css javascript react API'}
    ]

    return projetos.map(projeto => {
        return (<Projeto imagem={projeto.imagem} descricao={projeto.descricao} habilidade={projeto.habilidade}/>)
    })
}
```

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Modal } from "../modal/Modal";

const StyledProjeto = styled.div`
    width: 48%;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    position: relative;

    img {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
    }

    h3 {
        margin-bottom: .5rem;
        text-transform: capitalize;
    }

    p {
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
`

export const Projeto = ({imagem, descricao, habilidade, onMouseOver, onMouseLeave, isOpen}) => {
    return (
        <StyledProjeto onMouseLeave={onMouseLeave} onMouseOver={onMouseOver}>
            <div>
                <Modal isOpen={isOpen}/>
                {imagem}
            </div>
            <h3>{descricao}</h3>
            <p>{habilidade}</p>
        </StyledProjeto>
    )
}
```

o código roda, só que na minha cabeça as duas formas estão corretas, olhei qual q era o caminho da imagem na primeira tentativa e ele me deu um caminho absoluto, n sei se isso muda alguma coisa, pois quando eu tentei passar o caminho absoluto para qualquer uma das imagens ela n abria, se puderem me ajudar a entender, me dar uma direção ou algo para ler eu agradeço

Answer (score -2):

A segunda opção não é muito apropriada.

Ao invés de salvar a url da imagem, você pode salvar o caminho na sua variável de projetos com o require. Exemplo de um item:

```
{imagem: require('../../../img/aluraChallenge.png'), descricao: 'chalenge alura', habilidade: 'html css javascript api crud'}
```

Armazenando o dado dessa forma, você deve ser capaz de utilizar a imagem normalmente no componente como estava fazendo inicialmente.

```
<Projeto imagem={projeto.imagem} descricao={projeto.descricao} habilidade={projeto.habilidade}/>
```

Espero que dê certo.